# VBA Excel For loop with Variant Arrays crashing Excel

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, variant

Afternoon all.  I'm working on adding and undetermined number of values (customers) to a variant array using a For/Next loop and ReDim Preserve.  My code below:

```
lRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cCount = 0
uCount = 0

var_Events = sht1.Range("A2:BC" & lRow).Value2

For i = LBound(var_Events) To UBound(var_Events)

    ReDim Preserve var_Customers(0 To cCount)

    If Not CustInArray(str(var_Events(i, 2)), var_Customers) Then

        var_Customers(cCount) = str(var_Events(i, 2))
        cCount = cCount + 1

    End If

    If i Mod 100 = 0 Then

        MsgBox "Line: " & i

    End If

Next i
```

Here is the CustInArray function:`

```
Function CustInArray(str As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean

    CustInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, str)) > -1)

End Function`
```

I added the Mod/MsgBox after it crashed the first time to see where/when it was crashing with no errors.  It gets to about line 6000 before excel crashes (I don't see the "Line: 6000" MsgBox).

I've checked the UBound of the var_Events, and it is 6290 which is in line with the number of lines on my WS.  I also tried (UBound(var_Events) - 1), and still no luck.

I'm not 100% why it's crashing since there's no error, so that's all I can provide for now.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I mentioned this in the comments, but thought it would be good to add here.  I initially thought to use dictionaries, but this is just the first part of a longer process. Each customer is going to have an unknown number of items assigned to them, and an unknown number of classes to those items.

Comment: `Redim Preserve` an array thousands of times is very resource consuming and probably exhausted the memory. I urge you to start using a [Dictionary Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/dictionary-object).

Comment: The memory isn't exhausted, I checked after you mentioned it.  Never uses more than about 500MB (of 26GB available).  I initially thought to use dictionaries, but this is just the first part of a longer process.  Each customer is going to have an unknown number of items assigned to them, and an unknown number of classes to those items.

Comment: When you say `Crashes` what exactly does it do?  Does excel shut down and go away?  Is there an error?  Or does it freeze and go white?

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsc.htm). "*32-bit versions of Excel seem to have a memory limit of about 500MB for VBA (arrays, code etc)."*. **Dont assume** that VBA will effectively exploit all available memory on your system. It has inherent limitations. Besides I dont wee why a Dictionary wouldn't fulfill those requirements you mentioned.

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you!  I wasn't aware of that, but will keep it in mind.  This is a 64-bit version of Excel, is it still possible the 500MB limit exists in the 64-bit version?

Comment: @ScottCraner - Excel crashes ("Microsoft Excel has stopped working - checking on a solution"), disappears, then restarts ("Attempting to restart Excel").

Comment: *"is it still possible the 500MB limit exists in the 64-bit version?"*. Well, the limit is certainly bigger for 64 versions. BUT you should be careful not writing a *too resource aggressive* code. `Redim`ming an array actually has other problems related to memory fragmentation, *re-location* and *re-allocation* as the array grows... And at each time **both** copies of the array need to be present in the memory, which makes the memory requirement double up, in addition to the other fragmentation effects. (continued)

Comment: Seriously, redim the array one by one is an **extremely bad** design choice. For the least, allocate the maximum possible size at once then truncate the array at the end. But still bad. Dictionary is a possible alternative, not the only one though.

Comment: @A.S.H - Point taken.  In this example, it would be a Dictionary(_key_,_array(0 to x, 0 to y)_), correct?  I'm not familiar enough with Dictionaries to whip that out.  Any chance you could post a simple example?

Comment: There's an answer by @barrowc that seems worth trying first :). Let's see if it solves the problem before looking for other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start off with the array being large enough to hold a value from every row and then shrink it at the end with `ReDim Preserve` to the correct size:

```
lRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim var_customers(0 to lRow - 1)
cCount = 0
uCount = 0

var_Events = sht1.Range("A2:BC" & lRow).Value2

For i = LBound(var_Events) To UBound(var_Events)
    If Not CustInArray(str(var_Events(i, 2)), var_Customers) Then
        var_Customers(cCount) = str(var_Events(i, 2))
        cCount = cCount + 1
    End If

    If i Mod 100 = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Line: " & i
    End If
Next i

ReDim Preserve var_customers(0 to cCount)
```

There are better ways to do this, however, a Dictionary object (as pointed out in comments), the built-in "Remove Duplicates" command, or use ADO - like this:

```
' Set up connection
Dim cn As Object
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

' Connection string for Excel 2007 onwards .xlsm files
With cn
   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
End With

' Connection string for Excel 97-2003 .xls files
' It should also work with Excel 2007 onwards worksheets
' as long as they have less than 65536 rows
'With cn
'    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
'    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
'        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1"";"
'    .Open
'End With

' Create and run the query
Dim rs As Object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' Get all unique customers - assumes worksheet is named "Sheet1"
' and column name in cell B1 is "Customer"
rs.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Customer] FROM [Sheet1$];", cn

' Output the field names and the results
Dim fld As Object
Dim i As Integer

' Change the worksheet to whichever one you want to output to
With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    .UsedRange.ClearContents

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        i = i + 1
        .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
    Next fld

    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

    ' You could now read the range values back into a variant array if you wanted to
End With

' Tidy up
rs.Close
cn.Close
```